# Iterating through a table importing images

Tags: python, python-docx

Importing images using Python docx. Found some help from old post but unable to convert it to a 3 row, 2 col table.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
tables = document.tables
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
row_cells = table.add_row().cells

**for i, image in enumerate(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']):
    paragraph = row_cells[i].paragraphs[0]**
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture(image)
document.save('doc.docx')
```

I've adapted it to...

```
document = Document()
tables = document.tables

table = document.add_table(rows=3, cols=2)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
row_cells = table.add_row().cells

Inc1 = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg']
length =  len (Inc1)
for i in range(length):
for j in table.rows:
    for k in table.columns:
        paragraph = table.add_row().cells[i].paragraphs[0]
        run =  table.add_row().cells[i].paragraphs[0].paragraph.add_run()
        run.add_picture('1.jpg', width = Inches(1))

document.save('test.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding too many rows. You should have all the rows you need after the table is created. Access a row using `table.rows[i]` where `i` is in `(0, 1, 2)`.

So something like:

```py
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=3, cols=2)

Inc1 = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg']

for irow in range(3):
    for icol in range(2):
        paragraph = table.rows[irow].cells[icol].paragraphs[0]
        run = paragraph.add_run()
        run.add_picture(Inc1[(irow*2)+icol], width=Inches(1))

document.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks, to add captions(ie: Figure 1:) underneath it, I just need to add a line under run.add_pic(...)